# Show that pair of straight lines $ax^{2}+2hxy+ay^{2}+2gx+2fy+c=0$ meet coordinate axes in concyclic points. Also find equation of the circle

Tags: analytic-geometry

Show that pair of straight lines $ax^{2}+2hxy+ay^{2}+2gx+2fy+c=0$ meet coordinate axes in concyclic points. Also find equation of the circle through those cyclic points

**My Attempt:**

Given equation to the pair of straight lines is

$ax^2+2hxy+ay^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

Let the lines be

$l_1x+m_1y+n_1=0$
and 
$l_2x+m_2y+n_2=0$

Now what should I do next?

Comment: The equation in your title is quadratic in $x$ and $y$, and so is a conic section not a pair of straight lines. Do you mean for the lines to be tangents to this conic?

Comment: Even I don't know about that. Actually I got the question from a practice book.

Comment: @user335710 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5j4vz6bm8j

Comment: First off, for the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ to be equal you have to have $l_1l_2=m_1m_2$. A completely general pair of lines does not intersect the axes at concyclic points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $x=0$, $$ay^2+2fy+c=0$$

$$y_{1}y_{2} = \frac{c}{a}$$

Put $y=0$, $$ax^2+2gx+c=0$$

$$x_{1}x_{2} = \frac{c}{a}$$

Hence, $$x_{1}x_{2} = y_{1}y_{2}$$

By Converse of Intersecting chord theorem, the intercepts are concyclic.

> **Note briefly:**
>
> Note that it's also true for any non-degenerate conics such that $g^2>ac$,  $f^2>ac$ and $c\neq 0$.
>
> For two straight lines,
>
> $$\begin{vmatrix}
>     a & h & g \\
>     h & a & f \\
>     g & f & c
>   \end{vmatrix}=0$$

Now the equation of the required circle is

$$\fbox{$a(x^2+y^2)+2(fx+gy)+c=0$}$$

See the link [**here**](http://www.codecogs.com/library/maths/geometry/coordinate/pairs-of-straight-lines.php).

In the diagram below, $A=(x_{1},0), B=(x_{2},0), C=(0,y_{1}), D=(0,y_{2})$, $AB$ and $CD$ are the intersecting chords that meet at the origin $O$.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain me abit more?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: Ehh.  I understood............................?

Comment: I added a picture in my answer, hoping that helps.

Comment: Yes. It a bit more clear. But I am not familiar with finding the determinant of $3\times 3$ matrix. Could you make me understand that?

Comment: In general for conic $a x^2+2h xy+b y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0\,$, $\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
  a & h & g \\  
  h & b & f \\
  g & f & c
\end{vmatrix}=a b c - a f^2 - b g^2 - c h^2 + 2 f g h\,$.  In this case $\Delta=a^2 c - a f^2 - a g^2 - c h^2 + 2f g h\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by finding intercepts:

$$ax^2+2hxy+ay^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$

For x intercepts,

$$ ay^2 + 2fy +c = 0$$

For y intercepts,

$$ ax^2 + 2gx + c = 0$$

Let the points corresponding to root be: $(a,0) , (b,0) , (0,c) , (0,d)$

From this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898751/how-to-get-the-equation-where-a-circle-goes-through-three-points/2898773#2898773), the equation of circle through these points:

$$
   \det\begin{bmatrix}
     x^2 +y^2 & x & y & 1 \\
     b^2 & b & 0 & 1 \\
     c^2 & 0 & c& 1 \\
    d^2 & 0 & d& 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

For checking if $(a,0)$ is on this circle , simply plug it in place of $(x,y)$